# org.w3c.dom: Getting tag value only for the current Node

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am using [org.w3c.dom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) in Java to parse an XML document of the following form.

```
<Fields>
    <Field>
        <Key>Name</Key>
        <Length>20</Length>    <-- what if this is missing?
        <Subfields>
            <Field>
                <Key>First Name</Key>     <-- takes this as the first item
                <Length>11</Length>
            </Field>
            <Field>
                <Key>Second Name</Key>
                <Length>9</Length>
            </Field>
        </Subfields>
    </Field>
    ...
</Fields>
```

I am able to get the `<Field>` tag in the [Element](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) class. Now, to get the length (20), I have to do this

```
Node attribs = (Node)element.getElementsByTagName("Length").item(0);
```

The method `getElementsByTagName` returns a list of Lengths in all the descendants, and hence the first item is the length of the main field.

Problem arises, when the main field doesn't contain the length. In that case, the above expression gives the length of the first child node. Is there any way in which I get the tag value only for the current Node, and if that is not present, simply return `NULL`?

**EDIT:**

One way I found is to check if the item is the immediate child of the current field. This seems to work fine.

```
element==(Element)attribs.getParentNode()
```

But I believe there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only immediate children of node you can do it this way:

```
Node attribs = (Node)element.getElementsByTagName("Field").item(0);      
    Node childNode = attribs.getFirstChild(); // returns Key node     
    while( childNode.getNextSibling()!=null ){          
        childNode = childNode.getNextSibling();// returns all siblings of Key node
        if (childNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {         
            Element childElement = (Element) childNode;
```

This returns first child of `Field` and iterates over its siblings.